# Can I set up GNOME Terminal to have a toolbar?

Tags: gnome-terminal

In XFCE I used to like a terminal window to have a toolbar (with cut, copy, paste and new tab buttons). Can I enable it in Gnome Terminal?

Comment: Is it not an option to run the same terminal application that you used in XFCE under gnome ? If you have both installed on the same machine you should see this in the menus.

Comment: I am running GNOME Terminal 2.28.2 and I have file/edit/view/terminal/help options all there.

Answer (score 5):

```
$ sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal
...
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  exo-utils libexo-0.3-0 libexo-common libxfce4util-bin libxfce4util-common
  libxfce4util4 xfce4-terminal
After this operation, 10.0MB of additional disk space will be used.
...
$ xfce4-terminal &
$ gnome-terminal &
```

Ten megabytes is a little large for a terminal, but it does happily co-exist.

Answer (score 2):

There is no toolbar in GNOME Terminal and no option to add one. There is an optional menu (with File, Edit etc..) which you can enable/disable via the 'Show Menubar' option in the right click menu. If you really want a toolbar you will need to use a different terminal such as the xfce4-terminal you mentioned.

```
sudo apt-get install xfce4-terminal
```

Otherwise, you can use other methods to do the actions you want:

- **Copy** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or `Right Click -> Copy` or `Edit -> Copy`
- **Paste** - <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> or `Right Click -> Paste` or `Edit -> Paste`
- **New Tab** -  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or `Right Click -> Open Tab` or `File -> Open Tab`

I don't think there is a 'cut' action at all in GNOME Terminal.